# Google Cloud Compute Engine API Key To Manage VMs

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'd like to start/stop/restart VMs in GCP through scripts.  There are OAuth2.0 and API key methods for this.

For OAuth 2.0, I can generate access token through "gcloud auth print-access-token"  I get the key and it works.

I want to the same to work with API keys, but not able to find API key for "Compute Engine", there are service account, but keys.

curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxxx/zones/xxx/instances/xxx/stop?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed

what I am missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an API key for this purpose.  This is because the GCE API needs to know who is sending the request<sup>1</sup> but the API key doesn't provide this information.

API keys are used when an API can be accessed by anyone, for example a Google Maps box embedded in a website, but usage needs to be accounted to one particular customer.

<sup>1</sup> Identity is needed to enforce IAM permission, collect audit logs and other such tools.